# How to divide space equally between two elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following set up. It creates 3 groups of items, evenly distributed across the page. 
But I can't get the last bit to work. 
Where I have `.layeritem_inner` I want these to be divided evenly into two sections, but I can't get them to change size. 
I have tried various combinations of `flex-xxx` and `width` but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

```css
 #layerOneOuter
 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
 } 

 .layerOneInner
 {
  width:18em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:solid black 2px;
  text-align:center;
 }

 .layeritem_column_header
 {
  flex-basis: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #CFCFCF; 
  color: #000000;
 }

 .layeritem_column_row
 {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border:solid grey 1px;
  width:100%;
 } 

 .layeritem_inner
 {
  border:solid red 1px;
  width:5em;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="layerOneOuter">
  <div class="layerOneInner">
   <span class="layeritem_column_header">This is a Header</span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span> <!-- This row should take up 50% of the space -->
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span> <!-- This row should take up 50% of the space -->
   </span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span>
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="layerOneInner">
   <span class="layeritem_column_header">This is a Header</span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span> 
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span> 
   </span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span>
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="layerOneInner">
   <span class="layeritem_column_header">This is a Header</span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span>
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span>
   </span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span>
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign `display: flex;` to your `.layeritem_column_row` div, and then give `.layeritem_inner` a `width: 50%;`.

**CSS**

```
.layeritem_column_row
{
    display: flex;
}   

.layeritem_inner
{
    width:50%;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsx855jx/2/)**

Comment: that's great cheers. I'm sure I tried multiple variations of those options, just not in the right places or the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a percentage to keep it consistently half of the container holding it.

I also added box-sizing: border-box; into your item CSS. This includes the 1px from the red border into the 50% width.

Instead of something hard coded like 5em that's less dynamic.

```css
#layerOneOuter
 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
 } 

 .layerOneInner
 {
  width:18em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:solid black 2px;
  text-align:center;
 }

 .layeritem_column_header
 {
  flex-basis: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #CFCFCF; 
  color: #000000;
 }

 .layeritem_column_row
 {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border:solid grey 1px;
  width:100%;
 } 

 .layeritem_inner
 {
  border:solid red 1px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
  width:50%;
        display:block;
        float:left;
 }
```

```html
<div id="layerOneOuter">
  <div class="layerOneInner">
   <span class="layeritem_column_header">This is a Header</span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span> <!-- This row should take up 50% of the space -->
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span> <!-- This row should take up 50% of the space -->
   </span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span>
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="layerOneInner">
   <span class="layeritem_column_header">This is a Header</span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span> 
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span> 
   </span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span>
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="layerOneInner">
   <span class="layeritem_column_header">This is a Header</span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span>
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span>
   </span>
   <span class="layeritem_column_row">
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Left Side</span>
    <span class="layeritem_inner">Right Side</span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: box-sizing is a new one on me. I'll need to read up on that as it looks like it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

When I do something like that using flexbox, I normally prefer a flex-grow and flex-basis combination instead of using 'with' direct to the element. I don't see any flex-grow in your flex-items styles. Why aren't you using it? Any special reason? It would be an interesting variant, I believe...